# Alternative to append

Tags: python, for-loop, append

What is the good way for following python code:

```
          I = range(0,5000)     ## some list
          t = somevalue         ## for ex. 5    

          R = []     
          append1 = R.append     

          for i in I:      
              if i >= t:     
                 append1(1)
              else:
                 append1(0)
```

This code works fine but I think this is not a good way to do this. Also the append method is too much slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Append is slow because of in place replacement. Find way to create dynamic list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension seems to be what you need :

```
>>> I = range(0,10)
>>> t = 3
>>> R = [1 if i>=t else 0 for i in I]
>>> R
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
R = [int(val>=t) for val in I]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, this may be an alternative:

```
import numpy as np
I = np.arange(0,500)
t = 253
R = 1*(I >= t)
```

And if R needed to be a list you could add: `R.tolist()`